# SQL INSERT @tableVar SELECT ... is only insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to fill a dataset with values from several tables.

I've created a `stored procedure` that executes several `SELECT` statements.

Each `SELECT` has common parts.

I decided to cache the results of these common parts.

Now I need the `SELECT` construct that is capable of outputting the results to a table variable.

`INSERT @tableVar SELECT ...` only inserts data but does not select it.

My intention is something like `SELECT * OUTPUT SELECTED.* INTO @tableVar FROM ...`

Is it possible to perform such operation?

Comment: Please remove C# and .net tags as this only has to do with SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT @tableVar 
  OUTPUT INSERTED.* 
  SELECT * 
  FROM [...]
```

Comment: +1, SQL Server 2005+ has the `OUTPUT` clause, which permits a single `INSERT` statement to insert into two tables (original insert + output insert) as well as return a result set all simultaneously from a single statement.

Comment: This is very interesting solution, it's a pity that select doesn't allow nested insert with OUTPUT INSERTED.*, something like SELECT FROM (INSERT ... OUTPUT INSERTED.* ... )

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select after the first insert:

```
INSERT @probes
SELECT P.ID, P.ContainerID, P.EstimateID
FROM Probes AS P
WHERE P.LockedBy = @lockedBy

SELECT * FROM @probes

SELECT C.ID, C.Data
FROM Containers AS C
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT P.ContainerID
    FROM @probes AS P
) AS X ON C.ID = X.ContainerID

SELECT E.ID, E.ObjectiveID, E.[Time]
FROM Estimates AS E
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT P.EstimateID
    FROM @probes AS P
) AS X ON X.EstimateID = E.ID
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but is it possible to do in one operation?